# How to disable HTTP cache in iOS

Tags: ios, http, caching, nsurlconnection

As we all know that the standard HTTP protocol use 'Cache-Control' to manage cache. If we set 'max-age = negative number' for the key, NSURLConnection will not connect to network, but return the cache immediately. Recently, I run into a rediculous requirement. I was told to disable HTTP cache, event if the response header indicate that cache exists. And I can not set 'Cache-Control' for request header. Just like a browser. I know the iOS implement the standard HTTP protocol, I can't change the behavior of NSURLConnection. Any one can help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `NSURLSession` has ways to avoid caching (configuration properties, delegate methods, etc.). Perhaps you could migrate to this newer, more powerful API.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/URLCache) for `NSURLSessionConfiguration` says of that class's `URLCache` property:

> To disable caching, set this property to nil.

Therefore, you should create your `NSURLSession` using a configuration with `URLCache` set to nil:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
config.URLCache = nil;
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject 
                                                      delegate:self 
                                                 delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
```